# How to insert a specific unicode character (such as the ZWNJ symbol) into the text stream via lua code compiled by Lua(La)TeX?

Tags: symbols, luatex, unicode

How does one instruct Lua(La)TeX -- specifically, the lua code invoked via a `\directlua` directive -- to insert a non-ASCII unicode symbol, such as a "zero width non-joiner" symbol (code U+200C), into the text stream? I already know how to do this inside the body of a (Lua)LaTeX document -- I'd type something like

```
 stuff\char"200C{}morestuff
```

But how does one do this from inside lua code?

---

*Addendum* to (hopefully...) clarify what I'm trying to get done. If there's a string in the input stream such as `xyz123`, I'd like to insert a specific character (this evil invisible ZWNJ character...) between `xyz` and `123`, so that the input stream now is

```
xyz<ZWNJ>123
```

I already have the code to (i) find all instances of `xyz123` in the input stream and (ii) find the insertion point for the ZWNJ character inside the string `xyz123`. What I'm stuck with is trying to figure out how to insert the ZWNJ character (a "node" in luatex speak? of what type?) at the insertion location.

Comment: can't you just enter the character directly?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - The character ZWNJ is a "non-printing", i.e., invisible character. To main some debuggability of my code I'd rather not enter an invisible character directly. Instead, I want to provide the unicode "number" and have lua(tex) insert that character...

Comment: I don't know Lua, so I can comment only about the TeX side: I'd type `stuff\char"200C morestuff`, without the empty group. The space is ignored because it follows a required constant. Or also `^^^^200c` which is even better, because it's converted to the "real character" during tokenization. Since Lua code in `\directlua` is tokenized on the TeX side, it's possible that `^^^^200c` works.

Comment: @egreg -- thanks for this suggestion. I realize now I should have mentioned that the lua code sits in separate file (since doing just that is a frequently encountered recommendation...) and is invoked via the statement `\directlua{ require("myfile.lua") }`. :-(

Comment: @Mico oops that comment just invalidated my answer I'll update if I get the external version working:-)

Comment: Answer updated working with external code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In luatex, there is unicode library included. It acts as replacement for string library, so to print some unicode code point, you can use the char function:

```
function unicode2utf(c)
  -- As parameter pass hexadecimal unicode code point
  return unicode.utf8.char(tonumber(c,16))
end

print(unicode2utf("038F"))
```

This will print the omega symbol, as invisible space isn't best character to test :)

Comment: Thanks. I've provided an addendum to my posting, to be (hopefully) a bit clearer about what I'm looking to achieve. I used the term "print" a bit loosely in the original posting; I meant to say that I need to insert a certain character into the input stream.

Comment: +1 ah OK (that saves decoding the utf8 by hand) but I'll leave my answer there anyway as it has some alternatives (but @Mico should probably accept this:-)

Comment: @Mico see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114573/2891 for sample of generating text from luatex

Comment: Many thanks for this, both for the answer itself and for the pointer to the posting tex.stackexchange.com/a/114573/2891.

Comment: Nico's question was in the context of a standalone lua. Is there a Luatex library that can be "required" from lua standalone ?

Comment: @user1771398 LuaTeX uses modified version of Selene Unicode library

Comment: @michal.h21 I explored the LuaTex folders in search of a .lua file to require, in order to have unicode.utf8.char in the luaxml suite work, to no avail. Therefore I just substitued the "unicode.utf8.char" with "utf8.char" and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

The argument is processed by TeX before being passed to lua so you can use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}

\showoutput


z^^^^200cZ

\directlua{tex.sprint("a^^^^200cbc")}
\end{document}
```

which makes

```
....\EU2/Arial(0)/m/n/10 a
....\EU2/Arial(0)/m/n/10 ‌
....\EU2/Arial(0)/m/n/10 b
....\EU2/Arial(0)/m/n/10 c
```

showing a single invisible character between a and b

This also works if the tex.print is in an external file that is accessed via

\directlua{require('\jobname.lua') }

but in the external file

```
tex.sprint("x^^^^200cyz")
```

The lua string has 11 characters (bytes) the `^^^^` notation i sonly interpreted by TeX as it parses the output of `tex.print`

If you need the character to be available as such to lua functions rather than just in tex output you need to construct its utf8 encoding I think (update later)

If you need the character to be as such in a lua string then you can use `string.char` with its utf8 encoding

`\jobname.lua`

```
tex.sprint("x^^^^200cyz")
zwnj=string.char(226,128,140)
tex.sprint("v")
tex.sprint(zwnj)
tex.sprint("w")
```

`test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}

\showoutput


z^^^^200cZ

\directlua{tex.sprint("a^^^^200cbc")}

\directlua{require('\jobname.lua') }
\end{document}
```

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=10981513#10981513 `:)`